# How to save chat id to a file using telegraf (telegram framework)

Tags: node.js, telegram, telegram-bot

Here is my code for telegram bot hosted on Heroku. I'm using Telegraf Framework.

I'm trying to collect `From Chat ID` using `ctx.from.id` and save it to a file. I don't know why it's not saving.

```
const Telegraf = require('telegraf')
const express = require('express')
const fs = require('fs')

var BOT_TOKEN = "TOKEN-HIDDEN"

const expressApp = express()

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000
expressApp.get('/./', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Running')
})
expressApp.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`)
})


const bot = new Telegraf(BOT_TOKEN)
bot.start((ctx) => ctx.reply("Welcome to my chatbot"))
bot.startPolling()

fs.appendFile('file.txt', "ctx.from.id", function (err) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
    console.log('done');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There are few mistakes here

1: You wrote the function to save chat id outside of telegraf's functions .

2: You used `ctx.from.id` as/in **string** .

If you are trying to save the chat id on bot start then the code should be

```
bot.start((ctx) => {
    ctx.reply("Welcome to my chatbot");
    fs.appendFile('file.txt', ctx.from.id + ",", function (err) {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
        console.log('done');
    });
});
```